# Why can't I switch to my sniper rifle?

Tags: planetside-2

Whenever I select the Infiltrator class it won't let me switch to my sniper rifle. It instead forces me to use my sidearm.

Comment: There's a whole lot more detail that needs to be added here. Any specific version, anything you've done beforehand?

Comment: @Texenox What specific version would matter? The answer to this question is obvious but it seems that whoever voted to close the question hasn't actually played PS2 enough to understand how some classes work.

Comment: you may be using the stalker cloak which disables primary weapons

Comment: @Aequitas from the wiki: Stalker cloak does not drain energy as long as the infiltrator remains stationary, allowing the cloak to last indefinitely. However, stalker cloak prevents the use of the infiltrators primary weapon and regenerates slower than normal cloak.  Playing with the Stalker cloak most commonly felt close to using the CnD in TF2 as spy

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this is due to the type of cloaking you're using: [Stalker Cloaking](http://planetside.wikia.com/wiki/Stalker_Cloaking)

From the wiki:

> Stalker cloak does not drain energy as long as the infiltrator remains
>   stationary, allowing the cloak to last indefinitely. However, stalker
>   cloak **prevents the use of the infiltrators primary weapon** and
>   regenerates slower than normal cloak.

If you switch your cloaking to the [default, which is the Hunter Cloak,](http://planetside.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter_Cloaking) then you will be able to freely use your primary sniper rifle again.